# How do i read this function with a bunch of if statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    dictionary={
    49:3,50:1,51:3,52:2,53:3,
    54:2,55:1,56:3,57:3,58:1,
    59:1,60:1,61:2,62:2,63:2,
    64:3,65:2,66:2,67:3,68:3}
def fun(val):
    if val<1:
        return 1
    if val<3:
        return dictionary[53]
    if val<6:
        return dictionary[63]
    if val<8:
        return dictionary[53]
    if val<10:
        return dictionary[58]
    if val<19:
        return dictionary[66]+fun(4)
    return dictionary[65]+fun(val-9)+fun(val-17)
print(fun(26))
```

for this function, i know its recursing until it reaches a final number, which python tells me is 7. I have no clue how that number is found.
when i put print at the top of the function, it gives me 26,17,4,9,7. i don't know how the value goes down in that way.

Comment: There's no loop, why do you think it's running through a loop?

Comment: It's recursing when the argument is more than 19.

Comment: You have the impression that it is a loop but it is using recurstion. Read this to learn about it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/

Answer (score 1):

Here the loop runs for val = 26, since no if condition satisfies it, it reaches the last statement which is :

```
return dictionary[65] + fun(val-9) + fun(val-17) == 2 + fun(17) + fun(9)
                                                 == 2 + [2 + fun(4)] + 1
                                                 == 2 + [2 + 2 ]  + 1 
                                                 == 7
```

Comment: oh! okay thank you this makes a lot more sense! i appreciate your reply

Answer (score 1):

When the `val` argument is more than 19, none of the `if` conditions will succeed. So it executes the final statement

```
return dictionary[65]+fun(val-9)+fun(val-17)
```

This calls the function recursively. So if the argument was originally `26`, it calls `fun(17)` and `fun(9)`.

`fun(17)` executes the `if val<19:` branch, which also calls itself recursively:

```
return dictionary[66]+fun(4)
```

That's why you see `4` in your output.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of recursion. Basically, at first when you call 26, none of the if statements trigger so the function goes to the final return statement. Calling `dictionary [65]` returns 2, which is added to `fun(val-9)` which is `fun(17)`. Because this does trigger the final if statement, we go a layer deeper, so `fun(17)` will be equivalent to the sum of `dictionary[66]`, which is 2, and `fun(4)`, which calls the function again and triggers the third if statement, returning `dictionary[63]` which is 2. Adding 2 and 2 gives 4, which is the value of `fun(val - 9)`. Finally, `fun(val-17)` is `fun(9)`, which returns `dictionary[58]` which is 1. Adding, 2, 4, and 1 gives you 7 which is the final output of `fun(26)`.